# ¿como puedo resolver que no me deja rellenar el arreglo completamente?

Tags: c++

este es el código de mi programa,  cuando pide rellenar el arreglo de ips publicas v4 , solo me deja rellenar el primer espacio del arreglo  y hace ping al instante,en vez de pedirme todos los espacios del arreglo que el usuario a decidido, y hacer [x] números de pings a cada una de las ips del arreglo que el usuario a rellenado

¿como podría solucionarlo?

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib> 
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; 
    int ip;
    char m[100];
    cout<<"ingrese tamaño del arreglo de ipv4:";
    cin>>ip;
    cout << "ingrese cantidad de pings que se le va hacer a cada una de las ipv4 del arreglo :";
    cin >>dato;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i){
        
       for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
       {
        cout << "ingrese["<<i+1<<"] ipv4 del arreglo:";
        cin>>m[i];
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < dato; ++i)
      {
        stringstream comando;
        comando << "ping " << m[i];
        system(comando.str().c_str());
      }

    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

hola , edite el código, ahora si me deja rellenar el arreglo de ipv4 ,pero solo hace ping a la primera ipv4 del arreglo

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib> 
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; 
    int ip;
    string m[100];
    cout<<"ingrese tamaño del arreglo de ipv4:";
    cin>>ip;
    cout << "ingrese cantidad de pings que se le va hacer a cada una de las ipv4 del arreglo :";
    cin >>dato;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i){
        
       for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
       {
        cout << "ingrese["<<i+1<<"] ipv4 del arreglo:";
        cin>>m[i];
       }

         stringstream comando;
        comando << "ping " << m[i];

       for (int i = 0; i < dato; ++i)
      {
        
        system(comando.str().c_str());
      }

    }
 return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Honestamente leyendo el codigo no el encuentro sentido. Puedes añadir lo que
estas tratando de meterle al programa, y lo que te sale, y lo que esparabas que
saliera. De esa manera se nos hara mas facil ayudarte. PD: Para que mire cuando
lo hagas escribes un @ seguido de mi nombre en un comentario. Cuando lo tengas
vendre a hecharle un vistaso.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias por contestar mi pregunta , lo que espero del programa es que primero me pida el tamaño de la matriz de la ipv4 luego la cantidad de ("pings") que se le va hacer a cada una de las ipv4  que están dentro de la matriz  luego me pida rellenar la matriz y que por ejemplo: agá cien pings a la primera ipv4 de la matriz ,luego agá cien pings a la segunda ipv4 de la matriz  luego a la tercera y así asta que acabe con cada una de las ipv4 de la matriz

Comment: ¿A qué te referieres con eso de "_rellenar la matriz_"?? Si la matriz es de ipv4 ya la estás rellenando el primer paso, ¿no?

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Lees el largo de la ip, luego lees la cantidad de veces que se le hara ping, luego lees la ip, y finalmente haces el ping la cantidad de veces que te dijeron? @GregorioVaronRengifo

Comment: @Pablochaches   lo primero que quiero que haga es que le pregunte al usuario 
   cuantas ipv4 va a ingresar,que es la variable  ip , luego  la cantidad de veces que se le hará ping a cada una de las ipv4 que estan en el arreglo ,que es la variable dato ,luego empiece a rellenar el arreglo de ipv4 y luego agá [x][ es la variable dato] numero de pings a cada una de las ipv4 que están dentro del arreglo psd: corregí el código para que se entienda mejor

Comment: La respuesta de Joshin ya lo hace. Lo unico que tienes que añadir es que en lugar de sacarlos por la terminal sea un comando. En caso de que no compile usa `std::vector` en lugar de los VLA.

Comment: Creo que es importante mencionar que estás tratando de guardar strings en un array de **caracteres**.

Comment: @Pablochaches no entendió bien lo de usar el comando por la terminal , por favor podrías poner una respuesta con el código para poder entenderlo

Comment: Es lo mismo que haces aqui `stringstream comando; comando << "ping " << m[i];`

Comment: @Pablochaches en que parte del codigo pongo (stringstream comando;)?

Comment: En el lugar en el que el tiene el cout.

Comment: @Pablochaches y el comando<<"ping "<<m[i]; donde?

Comment: Una duda, si entiendes como funciona el codigo que tiene el o no? Tu escribiste
el codigo que publicaste orignialmente? Me parece que si a cualquiera de las 2
preguntas respondes afirmativamente deverias poder resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la solución según entendí tu consulta, me avisas si es lo que querías

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int dato; 
    int ip;
    
    cout<<"ingrese tamaño del arreglo de ipv4:";
    cin>>ip;
    cout << "Cantidad de ping para cada ipv4 :";
    cin >>dato;
    string m[ip];
    int n[ip] ;   
        
    for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
    {
        cout << "ingrese ipv4 del arreglo ["<<i+1<<"]:";
        cin>>m[i];        
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ip; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dato;j++){
            cout << "ping "<<m[i]<<endl;  
        }
        cout<<endl;               
    }    
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Los VLA que tienes en tu codigo son de C99. Ademas de que no son necesarios cuando tienes a la mano `std::vector`.

Comment: @joshin esa solución no es del todo correcta,debido a que debe hacer el comando ping  de la terminal de Windows, no que sea solamente un texto

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, he visto que tienes experiencia con estos problemas,  por favor podrías darme una solución a este problema